# Why did the examples of specflow always Uses the UI

Tags: specflow

I am newbie to BDD trying to understand it.. My  understanding about BDD was ..

**"Its a Kind of test where the user specfications are used to generate the Ubquitious language from the business"**

But the examples i am able to see only the example of UI.. Like when the button is pressed .. when the user enters the text ... this wont form a language which i can use in my code..

Am i wrong in understanding this concept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BDD (Behavior Driven Design) was a term coined by Dan North and the best source to understand his intent is [this excellent blog post](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/)

Here you can read that Dan want to shift focus from *testing details* to *describe behavior* instead. Of course this can (and sure has been) interpreted in oh so many ways :). So where ever you'll turn to you'll get an opinionated view - here is mine.

The idea with [Cucumber](http://cukes.info)-based tools, like SpecFlow, is to write down the teams shared understanding of a feature in a language and tool that all involved can read and understand. This is done (again in Cucumber-based tools) by writing down a couple of scenarios or examples on how the feature can be used. Some [people](http://gojko.net) call this specfication by example.

Some goodness comes out of writing the specifications by the use of examples in this way:

- you can discuss the behavior of the feature before it's implemented
- the specifications gives you a great specification to code after, using the [outside-in approach](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2010/05/29/outside-in-bdd/)
- the specifications over time becomes regression tests that verifies that the system behaves as specified
- the specification also comes through on a old TDD promise and becomes a living documentation for the system. You can easily see what the current state of an feature is by looking at the executable specification that the feature has passed

So now finally to your question (which by the way is a great one that I often have asked myself and others). Excuse me for rephrasing it, I hope I catch your intent:

> Do my scenarios have to (or should they) be run against the UI?

You sure don't have to run the scenarios against the UI - the principles of BDD and the tooling works great going against your domain in any layer.

But to get the most out of your specifications you should consider my (inconclusive) list above. If you don't include the GUI (or the database, or services etc.) then you cannot be sure that the whole application stack works correctly together. So very often the specifications are run End-to-end.

And this makes these "test" something very different than your unit-tests (which you want fast as lightning, mocking out external dependencies, not hitting the database etc.). They take longer time to execute, all of them should not be run on every check-in, the don't use mock etc.

Often you start out with a step of a scenario and as a driver for a behavior and then use ordinary TDD to drive out the details of the internal of the system. This is outside-in programming.

Finally to your example above. So I recommend you to run your specifications against the UI end-to-end all the way to the database; but I would advise describing the UI in technical terms as above (using buttons, links and textboxes for example). When I asked this question on the BDD Google Group I got a great tip from Elisabeth Keogh:

> Don't describe the UI. Describe instead what you're trying to achieve with the UI.

So to describe a login feature don't write:

```
Scenario: Login (describing the UI)
     Given I am on the Login-page
     When I enter 'AUser' in the textbox 'UserName'
       And I enter 'APassword' in the textbox 'Password'
       And I click the 'Login' button
     Then I should see the following text 'You are logged in'
```

rather write it something like this:

```
Scenario: Login (describing what we want to achieve)
     Given I am not logged in
     When I log in using 'AUser' and 'APassword'
     Then I should be logged in
```

That leaves the complexity on how this is done (click buttons, filling out forms, checking messages etc.) is done in the step definitions that you write in code.

I hope this was helpful. Also I am bracing myself for some "bashing" that can come from other, more experienced BDD-people. But hey, this is my two cents :)

Comment: When i seen Dan North Blog.. he has mentioned that **When trying to teach the TDD he had made this BDD where the Behaviour can been formed** My idea twowards it is take the feature and divide the step files in the layer where its required so when it run i can mock or Not depends on my requirement.. please let me know you opinion

Comment: @satish I like to think of the behavior as the behavior of the feature, as the user perceive it. So the steps are simple different steps that the user takes to perform the scenario, nothing about the systems layering or mocking at all in there.

Comment: Considering I have been getting into using BDD and SpecFlow recently this was a good encapsulation.  From Outside In is an apt description since you want to make these tests also understandable to those Outside Engineering.  Making sure the behavior is correct often gets lost in testing, sure much of it is through the UI but that is how Customers interact with the products and if they can't do what they expect - they won't come back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still pretty new to BDD and Specflow too. We've been using it to establish behaviour and code out the controllers, which in turn drive out the views. I don't have a code example in front of me, but I'll try to find something to post later. Cheers!

**edit** - BTW, if you're looking for a good book on using Cucumber (it uses the same language as Specflow - Gherkin? I'm still getting all the pieces straight), I can highly recommend **The RSpec Book** from Pragmatic Programmers. The code is Ruby based, but there are some higher level chapters on project definition and running. Well worth the price.